# Подключение IP камеры hikvisionк приложению QT

Tags: qt, ip, камера

Здравствуйте дорогие форумчане подскажите пожалуйста как подключить Ip камеру hikvision к Qt приложению для просмотра в реальном времени?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду приложение QuickTime, или что?

Comment: Нет. Приложение собственное и к нему нужно прикрутить просмотр с ip камеры hikvision

Comment: Читать документацию, в частности про класс QCamera и так далее